# Why i can not listen the child component routing changes in parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying to achieve that when I make some changes in a route, I want to open different cards and also close the cards. I have one parent component that includes closing the card function. When it triggers, it changes the browser route so then according to the route change I am trying to close the card but I don't know why my parent component is not re-rendering and getting the new updated browser state. I am using Next.js as a framework.

My first route is:
**/tasks#view=show&selected=T-1**

When I remove the hash from the route and close the card.
**/tasks**

But when I console the **view** variable I see that it does not event console it since it does not detect the change in route

Here my parent component (**RightV2SideBar**)

```js
export function RightV2SideBar({
  selectedTaskItem,
}: {
  selectedTaskItem: TaskItem | null;
}) {
  const url = new URL(window.location.href);
  const hash = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.slice(1));
  const view = hash.get('view');

  const onClose = () => {
    url.hash = '';
    url.searchParams.delete('view');
    url.searchParams.delete('selected');
    window.history.pushState({}, '', url.toString());
  };

  console.log('view', view);

  if (view === 'new-task' && !selectedTaskItem) {
    return <CreateTaskV2Card onClose={onClose} />;
  }

  if (view === 'new-bcf' && !selectedTaskItem) {
    return <CreateIssueV2Card onClose={onClose} />;
  }

  if (view === 'show' && selectedTaskItem) {
    return (
      <TaskInformationCard
        selectedTaskItem={selectedTaskItem}
        onClose={onClose}
      />
    );
  }

  if (view === 'edit' && selectedTaskItem) {
    return (
      <TaskInformationEditCard
        selectedTaskItem={selectedTaskItem}
        onClose={onClose}
      />
    );
  }

  return <h1>BcfIssue Card</h1>;
}
```

This is my child component(**TaskInformationCard**)

```js
export function TaskInformationCard({
  testId,
  onClose,
  selectedTaskItem,
}: TaskInformationCardProps) {
  const { t: p } = useTranslation('projects');
  const [query] = useModifyHistoryContext();

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-type-assertion/no-type-assertion
  const projectSlug = queryStringDefault(query.projectSlug, '') as ProjectSlug;
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-type-assertion/no-type-assertion
  const orgSlug = queryStringDefault(query.orgSlug, '') as OrganisationSlug;

  const { user } = useUser();

  const isTaskCreator =
    selectedTaskItem?.createdBy?.id === user?.['https://stnr.tech/global_id'];

  const { data: project } = useGetProjectQuery(
    { projectSlug, orgSlug },
    { skip: !projectSlug || !orgSlug }
  );
  const { format } = useDateFormat();

  const canManageTask = hasRole(project, Action.ManageTasks);

  const readOnly = !isTaskCreator && !canManageTask;

  const handleEditClick = () => {
    const url = new URL(window.location.href);
    const hash = new URLSearchParams(url.hash.slice(1));
    hash.set('view', 'edit');
    url.hash = hash.toString();
    window.history.pushState({}, '', url.toString());
  };

  return (
    <Card className="h-full gap-4 overflow-y-scroll" testId={testId}>
      <Card.Header
        actionButtons={<IconButton icon={XMarkIcon} onClick={onClose} />}
      >
        <Card.Title testId={testId && `${testId}-title`}>
          {p('task-information')}
        </Card.Title>
      </Card.Header>

      <div className="flex h-full flex-col justify-between ">
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-4">
          <TaskDetail
            label={p('task-form-name')}
            text={selectedTaskItem?.name ?? ''}
          />
          <TaskDetail
            label={p('task-form-assigned-to')}
            text={selectedTaskItem?.assignedTo?.firstName ?? ''}
          />
          <TaskDetail
            label={p('task-form-due-date')}
            text={
              selectedTaskItem?.dueDate
                ? format(new Date(selectedTaskItem?.dueDate), 'date-time', {
                    friendly: true,
                  })
                : ''
            }
          />
          <TaskDetail
            label={p('task-form-priority')}
            text={selectedTaskItem?.priority ?? ''}
          />
          <TaskDetail
            label={p('task-form-status')}
            text={selectedTaskItem?.status ?? ''}
          />
        </div>

        <div className="flex justify-end">
          {!readOnly && <Button onClick={handleEditClick}>{p('edit')}</Button>}
        </div>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel, and use [react-router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main) instead ^^

Comment: @moonwave99 what you mean by reinvent ? It is nextjs, I don’t use react router dom

Comment: Then use [nextjs routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing) ^^

Comment: Don't use `window.location`. That doesn't work in reactjs, since it's not a react state

Comment: @Bergi i dont know why window.location not working with hashing since it is working in client side